# ValueError: time data '2020-01-31T15:16:21+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Tags: python

I do have some trouble to get datetime to parse this time data. (This works in windows, but not on linux)

Can anyone tell my why this won't work on Linux?

```
d1 = '2020-01-31T15:16:21+00:00'

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

Comment: It would help if you included the code in question.

Comment: It's added now... though it looks the same as the title.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supposed to work in Windows either. The `%z` format does not support a colon between the hours and minutes of the timezone, as stated in the [datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). You'll need to remove the colon first:

```py
import datetime
import re

d1 = "2020-01-31T15:16:21+00:00"

# Remove all colons in the timezone part
d1 = re.sub(r"([\+-]\d\d):(\d\d)(?::(\d\d(?:.\d+)?))?", r"\1\2\3", d1)

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")  # now works normally
```

Expected `%z` format: `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]`

Explanation of what the regular expression, based on the above format, means: https://regex101.com/r/EoOBHW/1

---

Alternatively, you can use the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) third-party library, which parses that string successfully:

```py
import datetime

from dateutil.parser import parse

d1 = parse("2020-01-31T15:16:21+00:00")
```